# Error Generating the Pre-Authenticated URL from Oracle Cloud Storage (oci-java-sdk)

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

Getting the Error

```
com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (-1, null, false) Processing exception while communicating to: https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com (outbound opc-request-id: 610055D587CD432284C75AA1C52A6446)
```

I have taken the code units from the Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/PreauthenticatedRequest/CreatePreauthenticatedRequest but it does not work

Code

```
        final ConfigFileReader.ConfigFile configFile = ConfigFileReader.parseDefault();
        final AuthenticationDetailsProvider provider = new ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider(configFile);

        ObjectStorageClient client = new ObjectStorageClient(provider);
        log.debug("Client Created = "+client.getEndpoint());

        /* Create a request and dependent object(s). */
        CreatePreauthenticatedRequestDetails createPreauthenticatedRequestDetails = CreatePreauthenticatedRequestDetails.builder()
                .name("EXAMPLE-name-Value")
                .bucketListingAction(PreauthenticatedRequest.BucketListingAction.ListObjects)
                .objectName("230222082346340.pdf")
                .accessType(CreatePreauthenticatedRequestDetails.AccessType.ObjectReadWrite)
                .timeExpires(new Date("Wed Nov 26 03:00:33 UTC 2042")).build();

        log.debug("createPreauthenticatedRequestDetails Created..."+createPreauthenticatedRequestDetails.getName() );

        CreatePreauthenticatedRequestRequest createPreauthenticatedRequestRequest = CreatePreauthenticatedRequestRequest.builder()
                .namespaceName("namespacename")
                .bucketName("temp")
                .createPreauthenticatedRequestDetails(createPreauthenticatedRequestDetails)
                .opcClientRequestId("ocid1.test.oc1.."+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"-opcClientRequestId-Value")
                .build();

        CreatePreauthenticatedRequestResponse response = client.createPreauthenticatedRequest(createPreauthenticatedRequestRequest);
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Complete Error Log:

```
09:02:25 INFO [co.or.bm.ht.ApacheConfigurator]Setting connector provider to ApacheConnectorProvider
09:02:25 INFO [co.or.bm.ob.ObjectStorageClient]Setting endpoint to https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com
09:02:25 DEBUG[or.fr.co.DocStoreOracleService]Client Created = https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com
09:02:25 DEBUG[or.fr.co.DocStoreOracleService]createPreauthenticatedRequestDetails Created...EXAMPLE-name-Value
com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (-1, null, false) Processing exception while communicating to: https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com (outbound opc-request-id: 813E7CD051BD44FB9303B033D912F187)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.convertToBmcException(RestClient.java:994)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.post(RestClient.java:306)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.lambda$null$12(ObjectStorageClient.java:684)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.doFunctionCall(BmcGenericRetrier.java:89)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.lambda$execute$0(BmcGenericRetrier.java:60)
    at com.oracle.bmc.waiter.GenericWaiter.execute(GenericWaiter.java:55)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.execute(BmcGenericRetrier.java:51)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.lambda$createPreauthenticatedRequest$13(ObjectStorageClient.java:680)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.doFunctionCall(BmcGenericRetrier.java:89)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.lambda$execute$0(BmcGenericRetrier.java:60)
    at com.oracle.bmc.waiter.GenericWaiter.execute(GenericWaiter.java:55)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.execute(BmcGenericRetrier.java:51)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.createPreauthenticatedRequest(ObjectStorageClient.java:674)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocStoreOracleService.generatePAUNew(DocStoreOracleService.java:774)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocStoreOracleService_Subclass.generatePAUNew$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocStoreOracleService_Subclass$$function$$8.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocStoreOracleService_Subclass.generatePAUNew(Unknown Source)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocStoreOracleService_ClientProxy.generatePAUNew(Unknown Source)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocumentResource.getPreAuthURL(DocumentResource.java:36)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocumentResource_Subclass.getPreAuthURL$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocumentResource_Subclass$$function$$4.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at org.freshfood.controller.DocumentResource_Subclass.getPreAuthURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:91)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: java.lang.String
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:321)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:494)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:226)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ForwardingInvocationBuilder.post(ForwardingInvocationBuilder.java:157)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.lambda$post$4(RestClient.java:304)
    at com.oracle.bmc.circuitbreaker.internal.JaxRsCircuitBreakerImpl.lambda$decorateSupplier$0(JaxRsCircuitBreakerImpl.java:83)
    at io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker.lambda$decorateSupplier$4(CircuitBreaker.java:198)
    at com.oracle.bmc.circuitbreaker.internal.JaxRsCircuitBreakerImpl.lambda$decorateSupplier$1(JaxRsCircuitBreakerImpl.java:93)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.lambda$decorateSupplier$0(RestClient.java:175)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.post(RestClient.java:304)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: java.lang.String
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:302)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.syncProceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:224)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:446)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:625)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.buildEntity(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:584)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.loadHttpMethod(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:489)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:299)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: Hi - what version of Java SDK are you using?

Can you provide full stack trace?

Also, you need to sub in your specific namespace name, bucket name, and object name in the above. Did you do that?

Are you able to call other Object Storage operations for the same region?

Are you able to call this Object Storage operation in a different region? If you get an error doing so, is it the same error or a different one?

Comment: JDK Version: openJDK 11.0.10. Error : com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (-1, null, false) Processing exception while communicating to: https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com (outbound opc-request-id: 1676B005643549868464EF71ED348DE9)
 at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.convertToBmcException(RestClient.java:994)
 at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.RestClient.post(RestClient.java:306).

I am able to call list objects, delete object but having problem with create and generating pre-authenticated URL and Creation of object in storage.
All the info are passed correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for OCI Java SDK version, not Java version itself. Also, that doesn't look like the full exception stack trace - can you modify your original question to have the full stack trace?

Comment: oci-java-sdk-objectstorage : 2.17.0.  Object listing, delete works fine. However the same error comes for Pre-Authenticated URL and creating object. I guess all the write operations.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use the SDK with Resteasy. Have you looked at and followed the Resteasy section here? https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/javasdkconfig.htm#Using

Also, are you able to do write operations against other OCI services from the SDK? I'm wondering if the issue you are facing isn't Object Storage related, but rather an issue doing any write operations (PUT/POST) calls to OCI

Comment: Yes I am not able to create an object as well. Only listing and Delete works.

Comment: Yes but can you create resources in other OCI services? Ex: Compute, Virtual Networking, etc. And did you review and follow the link I sent?

Comment: Same Issue here, in the beginning, the put function that calls OCI bucket worked fine, and after a few days stop working and showed the same error message down, and need to restart the container to work again!!

Error Message:

(-1, null, false) Processing exception while communicating to: https://objectstorage.me-jeddah-1.oraclecloud.com

Please share if you find any workaround for this!?